# Moving vectors to the left and the right of a product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $1\times n$ row vectors and $x$ is a $n\times 1$ column vector. I have an expression 
$$
(Ax)^2B'B
$$ 
which is an $n\times n$ matrix.

**Question**: Is it possible to write the expression as a **proper matrix product** of the form $f(x)Cg(x)$ (e.g. $x C x'$)? By "proper" I mean that there is dimension compatibility among $f(x)$, $C$, and $g(x)$ where each of these is treated as matrix.

My motivation for doing this is that I would like to sum over these expressions. In such a sum, $A$ and $B$ change with the summation index but $x$ doesn't.

The best I can do is as follows. First, I transform $(Ax)^2B'B$ (written as a scalar times a matrix) into a proper matrix product, and then I manipulate things:
\begin{align*}
(Ax)^2B'B=B'(Ax)^2B=B'x'A'AxB.
\end{align*}
The dimensions check out: for example, for the rightmost expression above, we have
$$
(\underset{B'}{n\times 1})(\underset{x'}{1\times n})(\underset{A'}{n\times 1})(\underset{A}{1\times n})(\underset{x}{n\times 1})(\underset{B}{1\times n})\to n\times n
$$
but I still have the $x$'s "inside" the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my misgivings about your use of the word "proper". But, if what you want is "column-scalar-scalar-row", then you can write
$$
B'Axx'A'B. 
$$

If what you want is an expression $xCx'$, then $C$ may not exist. For starters, $C$ is necessarily $1\times1$, so a number $c$. The equality is then
$$
c\,xx'=(Ax)^2B'B=B'AxxA'B.
$$
If we multiply by $x'$ on the left and by $x$ on the right, 
$$
c\,(x'x)^2=x'B'Axx'A'Bx=|x'A'Bx|^2,
$$
so 
$$
c=\frac{|x'A'Bx|^2}{(x'x)^2}.
$$
You want this expression to not depend on $x$. If we take $x$ to be a unit vector, then $x'A'Bx$ is the $1,1$ coordinate of $A'B$ in a basis that starts with $x$. So the diagonal of $A'B$ is constant in any basis; this implies that $A'B=\lambda I_n$. But $A'B$ is rank-one, so $\lambda=0$. It follows that $A'$ and $B$ are orthogonal.

In other words, you can only find $C$ such that $xCx'=(Ax)^2B'B$ precisely when both sides are zero.

Comment: I clarified the question. I'm hoping that the $x$'s can either be the leftmost or the rightmost so that I can factor the $x$'s out when I sum over things. In that sum, the $x$'s do not vary with the summation index.

Comment: But you cannot have one $x$, because then the expression would be linear on $x$, while the original is quadratic. So, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I want something of the form, say, $x C x'$ (also $n\times n$ and quadratic in the components of $x$) so that I can do something like $\sum_Cx C x'=x[\sum_CC]x'$.

Comment: Did you  notice that to be able to make $xCx'$, you need $C$ to be $1\times 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $Ax$ is a scalar, so that it equals its own transpose, how about:
$$
(Ax)'B'B(Ax)=x'A'B'BAx
$$

Comment: I see what you're doing there. But I'm looking for a proper matrix product where the things that depend on $x$ are either on the leftmost or on the rightmost. What you have is scalar * column * row * scalar whereas a proper product has the form column * scalar * scalar * row.